# Unsupported software?

Tags: lubuntu, unsupported-packages

I came across this command in the [lubuntu users mailing list](https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/lubuntu-users/2013-October/005872.html):

```
ubuntu-support-status --show-all
```

When I ran it after `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`, the summary at the top shows this:

```
[11:38 AM] ~ $ ubuntu-support-status --show-all
Support status summary of 'vasa1-Inspiron-1545':

You have 1059 packages (82.5%) supported until July 2014 (9m)

You have 224 packages (17.4%) that are unsupported
```

Among the "unsupported" software, I see:
aria2
audacity
flashplugin-installer
geany
gnome-icon-theme-full
gnome-mplayer
gnome-system-tools
openbox
pcmanfm
synaptic
thunar
ttf-mscorefonts-installer

My OS is Lubuntu 13.10.

Any idea why such common software is shown as "unsupported"?

My question may be related to [How do you use or what is wrong with ubuntu-support-status?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/211848/how-do-you-use-or-what-is-wrong-with-ubuntu-support-status) but I don't think it's a duplicate.

And I don't think it's covered by this bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/update-manager/+bug/849532

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's been [pointed out](https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/lubuntu-users/2013-October/005885.html) that "unsupported" in this context is just that *Canonical isn't responsible for providing support for the particular package from **Day 1*** of a release.

From a non-comprehensive use of `apt-cache show package_name`, it appears that supported  packages, found with `ubuntu-support-status --show-supported`, are in the **main** pool and also in the **restricted pool** as noted by [Ibere Fernandes](https://askubuntu.com/users/106510/ibere-fernandes)  in the [lubuntu users mailing list](https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/lubuntu-users/2013-October/005895.html).

For example, running `apt-cache show zenity`, a supported package has this line:
`Filename: pool/`**`main`**`/z/zenity/zenity_3.8.0-1_amd64.deb`
and
`Supported: 9m`

And, running `apt-cache show fglrx` has:
`Filename: pool/`**restricted**`/f/fglrx-installer/fglrx_13.101-0ubuntu3_amd64.deb`
and
`Supported: 9m`

But, running `apt-cache show thunar`, an unsupported package, has:
`Filename: pool/`**`universe`**`/t/thunar/thunar_1.6.3-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb`
and no mention of a support period.

This, from [What are Repositories?](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Ubuntu), is relevant:

> The repository components are:
>     Main - Officially **supported** software.
>     Restricted - Supported software that is not available under a completely free license.
>     Universe - Community maintained software, i.e. **not officially supported** software.
>     Multiverse - Software that is not free.