# Can I list all the programs installed that do not have a repository?

Tags: repository, 19.04

While upgrading to Ubuntu 19.04, one of the steps said something along the lines of "Removing third party repositories"

After the installation finished, everything worked mostly OK, but a few applications were giving me trouble, which was fixed by adding their ppa again and applying an update.

But now I don't know for sure how many other programs do I have installed that are not getting properly updated. Is it possible to list all the programs I have installed that do not have a repository so I can go look for them again?

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://askubuntu.com/questions/368329/unsupported-software

Comment: But the link above won't cover software you've installed by a process **not** using dpkg.